# Transition-Origin IS NOT APLLYING

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I was trying to make a cross for my menu but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code and I am also using js to rotate it by 45 deg: Even after changing the origin it is not working and refuses to make a perfect cross. [IMAGE OF THE CROSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC7s5.png)

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                let nav = document.getElementById('nav-toogle')
                let bars = document.querySelectorAll(".open")
                let active = false;
                document.querySelector('#nav_menu').addEventListener('click', function(){
                    if(!active){
                        bars[0].style.transform = "rotate(45deg)"
                        bars[1].style.opacity = "0"
                        bars[2].style.transform = "rotate(-45deg)"
                        nav.style.maxHeight = "0vh";
                        nav.style.minHeight = "100vh";
                        active = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        bars[0].style.transform = "rotate(0deg)"
                        bars[1].style.opacity = "1"
                        bars[2].style.transform = "rotate(0deg)"
                        nav.style.minHeight = "0vh";
                        nav.style.maxHeight = "0vh";
                        active = false;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu" id="nav_menu">
       <span class="open"></span>
       <span class="open"></span>
       <span class="open"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.open{
   width: 30px;
   height: 1px;
   background-color: var(--secondary);
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   transform-origin: left;
   }

.menu{
   position: fixed;
   top: 3.5em;
   right: 3.5em;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   display:none;
   cursor: pointer;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing styling in JS can get messy fast so I recommend toggling a css class

```
const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav_menu');
navMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    navMenu.classList.toggle("cross");
})
```

For the css you don't need the `tranform-origin`. A `translateY` is enough here

```
#nav_menu.cross .open:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(45deg);
}

#nav_menu.cross .open:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

#nav_menu.cross .open:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much it really helped me!!